# `Missing } inserted' when apacite is loaded; no error when it's not loaded

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, installing, apa-style

I'm writing a thesis, and want to use the APA citation style. I've installed the apacite package. Possibly incorrectly, but TeXworks does not give any errors concerning the package. It does give errors with all `\cite{}` commands, which seem to mess up with the `\begin{}` and `\end{}` commands. If I comment out the `\usepackage{apacite}` statement, everything works just fine (even if I keep the bibliographystyle `apacite`!)
Anyone who has any idea what could be happening here? Thanks in advance!

Some example errors:

```
! Missing } inserted.

l. 19 Charles Darwin on language \cite{Darwin71}

?

! Too many }'s.

l.20

?

!Latex error: \begin{document} ended by \end{quote}
```

And this is the master file I try to typeset:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book} 

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{makeidx} %If you want to generate an index, automatically 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document} 

\author{Ellen Maassen} 
\title{Language as a Threefold Adaptive System \newline\\ {\Large The Emergence of Phonological Compositionality}}
\date{\today} 

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents 
\include{preface}

\mainmatter 
\input{chaptr12}
\input{chaptr22} 
\input{chaptr32} 
\input{chaptr42} 
\input{chaptr52}  
\input{chaptr62}
\input{chaptr72}

\appendix
\input{Geluidjes}
\input{bootstrapping}

\backmatter  
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{refs} 
\printindex 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `natbib` AFTER `apacite` and you should have no problems.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Any feedback about what karlkoeller proposed to solve your problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller Please add that as answer.

Answer (score 6):

This problem can be resolved simply loading the package `natbib` after `apacite`.

Note that you can avoid loading `natbib` if you pass the option `natbibapa` to `apacite`.

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

In this way `apacite` loads `natbib` with the options `longnamesfirst` and `sort`, needed in order to meet the APA specifications.